# spacemacs/dired-aux rename file to similar name without ivy/counsel trying to rename to same file name

Tags: spacemacs, dired, completion

In spacemacs I find that two ways to get a new copy of a file with a slightly different filename both suffer from the same completion problem:

1. C-x C-w (`write-file`)
2. dired-aux's `dired-do-rename` (bound to `R` in spacemacs in `dired`)

Either way, if I type the initial part of the existing filename, hoping to get a completion, and then `TAB` to complete, I get the completion to the existing file name that I was after.  However, also, the rename operation is actually run immediately when I hit `TAB`, which always fails with `Cannot move to same file: /path/of/very_long_file_name_indeed.something.something`.  What I want is to get just the completion, so that I can edit the new filename to say `very_long_file_name_indeed_renamed.something.something`, without typing out the full original filename first.

I expect probably what I want here is to ask something (ivy? counsel? dired-aux? dired?) to only complete, not execute the rename.

How do I complete the filename so that I can edit it before emacs tries to rename the file?

Comment: I don't see this (or perhaps your recipe isn't clear enough? - consider giving a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`). For me, `TAB` just completes - it doesn't also start renaming/moving the file. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew It looks like the 'completion behavior' when selecting the filename directly is different from when selecting the filename by/after 'typing first'. Also, I'm not sure, but maybe Spacemacs modifies default Ivy behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean. I know that Ivy's completion behavior can be configured to behave differently, so if you really want to, then you can check its documentation.

However, if you just want to get a copy with a slightly different name, then you can achieve that, from a buffer visiting the file to be renamed (not from dired), by pressing `SPC u SPC f c` (`SPC f c` is for copying the file, and by passing the universal argument `SPC u` the original filename already gets inserted for you). Then in Ivy you should select the input line by moving up using `C-k` (or the arrow up key). Now you can modify the name and press `RET` when finished.

Comment: For me the file path that gets inserted is (following my original example) `/path/of/of` -- i.e. the filename of the directory itself is appended to the directory path, instead of filename of the regular file whose name I want to edit.  I tried that on the latest commit on spacemacs develop.

Comment: Did you press `SPC u` `SPC f c`? It seems unlikely to me that the path of the original file is getting inserted, as the code that is used for reading the filename is the following: `(read-file-name "Save buffer as: " nil nil nil (buffer-name))`. So, when you call it correctly, then it should just insert the `(buffer-name)`. Otherwise, can you upload an image/screenshot?

Comment: Ahh, sorry you're suggesting doing that *from a buffer visiting the file*, I thought you were suggesting doing that from dired.  That works!  Edited the answer to make that explicit